# I need a help for regexp in javascript code

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var str = "^" + "/post/\d+" + "$";
var regex = new RegExp(str);
var flag = regex.test("/post/3333");

console.log(flag) // -> false
console.log(regex) // -> /^\/post\/d+$/
```

I'm expecting the result becomes true, but it results in false.

I think the problem is "\" is added automatically before "/" when RegExp instance is created.

How am I supposed to write in order to make it work?

Comment: When using `RegExp` constructor, you need to escape the backslashes twice. Once for the string and next for the regex. Use `"^" + "/post/\\d+"`

Comment: You printed out the value of `regex`--good debugging technique! Once you've done that, the problem is staring you in the face. You will see it says `/^\/post\/d+$/`. Note that the slashes have been transformed into `\/` as they should, but the `d` has no preceding backslash! So it will just match an actual `d`! This would have been a great clue for you to start understanding what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more specific regular expression to match the format of `/post/####`:

```
var regex = /\/post\/[0-9]+$/;
var flag = regex.test("/post/3333");
```

This will test for the string `/post/` followed by one or more digits, occurring at the end of the line.

[image]

Likewise:

```
var regex = /\/post\/[0-9]{4}$/;
var flag = regex.test("/post/3333");
```

will test for the string `/post/` followed by 4 digits, occurring at the end of the line.

[image]

Comment: The 2nd image says "3 times" intead of 4, is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, it's 3 times in addition to the first time. So it matches a single number once, then 3 more times. It is confusing upon first glance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `new RegExp` constructor and string
Here example

```
var regex = /post\/\d+$/;
var flag = regex.test("/post/3333");
```

I removed `^` flag, because regex will not work with this format of input "website/post/3333"

Comment: I need new RegExp constructor because I have a variable that I want to expand in regexp literal.